# Unusual and Unwanted Keyboard beep

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard impacted today and is not working properly now :(
It`s produce a beep sound when below keys are pressed:

Ctrl [left\right] + Space

Ctrl [left\right] + G

Ctrl [left\right] + H

Ctrl [left\right] + Alt [left]

Ctrl [left] + Insert

Up + Left (yes! just two keys)

and some others that i can't notice it until now ...

Can anyone help me to understand what problem was occurred?

Update 1:

I`m using win 7 SP1 x64 and problem is Global in every where after my little brother punched my keyboard.

Beep sound can be heard trough the speakers not main-board anytime.

There is also:

Ctrl [left\right] + Up Arrow

Ctrl [left] + Home

Ctrl [left] + Delete

Ctrl [left] + Page Up

Update 2:

In below software every keys was OK:

http://www.passmark.com/products/keytest.htm

I`m confused what exactly happened to my keyboard

Update 3:

Finally: I opened the back of my keyboard and saw it. Then I closed it and now the problem is solved!!!

I still do not know what the problem was.

thank you anyone for your help and time ;)

Comment: Please add information on which operating system you are using and in which applications the sound occurs.

Comment: You say it beeps.  When it does this is the key recognized (eg, in an editor) or is it ignored?  In any event it sounds like a stuck key.  Have you tried rebooting (on the off chance that the "stuck key" is purely a software mode switch)?

Comment: And have you tried "punching" the keyboard again?

Comment: (Is this a separate keyboard or one built in to a laptop or whatever?  Wired or wireless?)

Comment: Yes, i punched it again but no any differ :|

Comment: In my previous keyboard and this one (both are wired and separate), in need for speed and every where, hitting three keys of [ Alt + Up + left ] produces the beep sound and last key that was pressed don't functioned that this is a normal and usual beep sound but now i have many problems in [ Ctrl + Space ] for programming, [ Ctrl + G/H ] for finding and replacing and so on ... in Netbeans IDE or Firefox or ... and same situation like normal beeps that last key will not function normally :((

Answer (score 0):

One of the keys on the keyboard may be stuck.  Open up a text editor so you can see the result of pressing keys, and start pressing each key in turn.  You may not see anything unusual when you press the stuck key - pressing it may just cause it to become unstuck.  Or you may find that you are unable to press the key because it is stuck, which will identify for you the key that is the problem.  After you've tried all of the keys on the keyboard, try the problematic combinations you listed above again and see if the problem has been resolved.

I've found that some software can cause my keys to become "virtually" stuck - the Windows Remote Desktop tool does this to me sometimes.  After switching back to my desktop from the remote desktop, it acts like I'm holding down either the Windows key, Alt key, or Ctrl key.  Pressing each of these keys fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you man. I`m tried that way you said but problem is still available :( ... can it be due to a hardware error or something like that?